# range as input in python

Tags: python, fibonacci

this is a simple program for Fibonacci series . its running perfectly for fixed range. but i would like to know is it possible to get range as input? if so please let me know the syntax to get range as input.

```
xx=0

x=float (raw_input("enter the starting number:"))

r1=xx+x

print r1

r2=r1+x

print r2

r3=r1+r2

print r3

for i in range(10):

     r4=r2+r3

     print r4

     r2=r3

     r3=r4
```

""" looking for answers"""

Comment: Based on how the question is worded it seems as though this is a homework question...we're here to help but not do homework.

Comment: @confusedandamused [It's okay to ask about homework](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @VincentSavard It is okay to ask for hints/help but "looking for answers" seems to be requesting a whole solution.

Comment: Are you looking to produce a range of fibonacci numbers starting at some index, or are you trying to produce a fibonacci-like sequence starting with some number?

Comment: @VincentSavard Which is great and all, but please read the things you link before you send them to others...OP hasn't 1. Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. 2. Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. 

I'm all for helping people but copy/paste questions are not appreciated if no previous steps/attempts have been made.

Comment: @JohnColeman and confusedandamused: The fact that this question is poorly asked is completely irrelevant to the fact that homework questions are allowed. Judge a question based on its own merit, not because it is or it isn't homework.

Comment: its not home work. i am beginner in python. i myself searching question in online and coding on my own.  my question is just i want to know is it possible to get range as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like you asked for the starting number:

```
number_of_outputs = int( raw_input('Enter the number of outputs: '))

#Your code goes here

for i in range(number_of_ouputs):

    #More code goes here
```